# Which service creates /dev/fb0 node?

Tags: systemd, devices, startup, framebuffer

I want to update the `console-setup.service` to detect screen resolution using `fbset -s` and adjust console font size accordingly. For `fbset`, I need `/dev/fb0` to be present, but I don't know which service I should create a dependency on. How is `/dev/fb0` created on startup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/dev/fb0` is created by the kernel as soon as the first framebuffer display driver has detected and initialized the respective display controller hardware.

If that driver is built into the kernel, it might effectively already be there when userspace processes start running.

If you add a udev rule like:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="graphics", KERNEL=="fb0", TAG+="systemd"
```

you should get a `*.device` unit for it, which you can then use for dependencies.

If you add `ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="your.service"` to the udev rule, udev will tell systemd to start your service as soon as this device appears, so you could run `fbset` as a separate service if it suits your plans.

At least Debian 12 has `console-setup.service` run `After=console-screen.service kbd.service local-fs.target`, but `console-screen.service` does not seem to be defined. So you might define your own `console-screen.service` that runs your `fbset` and console font operations, and have udev trigger it with

```
SUBSYSTEM=="graphics", KERNEL=="fb0", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="console-screen.service"
```

as soon as the device becomes available.

Then the order of operations would be: `/dev/fb0` appears -> your custom `console-screen.service` runs -> `console-setup.service` runs.

You could then configure the standard `console-setup.service` to leave the console font alone, and instead set it in your custom `console-screen.service`.